# Are there any contactless IR temperature sensors availbe for a range above 380C?

Tags: sensor, temperature

I need to measure the temperature of something without contact as part of an embedded electronics project ([this](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/temperature-sensors-humidity-sensors/9128794/) sort of form factor would be ideal), and need a range up to 500C. There are IR guns (for cooking, baking etc.) on [Amazon for up to 750C](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B01AT9TON0/ref=dp_prsubs_2) for reasonably cheap (>£50), but I can't find any sensors from the usual distributers (RS, Mouser, Farnell, DigiKey etc.) which go above 380C to integrate into an embedded electronics project. There are [contact sensors for up to 500C](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/platinum-resistance-temperature-sensors/6117801?cm_mmc=UK-PLA-DS3A-_-google-_-CSS_UK_EN_Automation_%26_Control_Gear_Whoop-_-Platinum%20Resistance%20Temperature%20Sensors_Whoop-_-PRODUCT_GROUP&matchtype=&aud-659911584228:pla-341406210377&gclid=CjwKCAjwqJ_1BRBZEiwAv73uwJoJCZY4tfljLGsVST7Byl1nOhjbfPez9-cBD3WSk0PslsfFPi0KjxoCsuwQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds), for very cheap (~£3) which is great, but I would expect to find some contactless ones too, especially since the technology obviously exists for the guns to work.

Does anyone know the technology that these guns use, and if they can be used in electronics projects?

Comment: you answered your title question yourself ... the answer to your second question is `yes`

Comment: Sorry I wasn't very clear, I am looking for a sensor to use as part of an embedded electronics project. I'm assuming that whatever sensor the IR cooking guns use would suit my needs but I can't seem to find anything which has that range.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE but please note that direct shopping questions will result in fairly prompt closure of your question as per [site rules](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Apologies, I'm not looking for a direct shopping question, just wanting to know if such a sensor exists. I mean, I'm assuming it does exist as the IR guns exist but I'm just looking for advice on the technology that can achieve this - whether it's feasible I suppose. Maybe there's a better way I can word my question to fit with the rules. Thanks for your comment

Comment: @Robert, my comment is meant to alert you to the fact that your two questions are not asking for information that you need ... they both have a simple yes/no answer, which is probably not what you want ... if you wish to clarify your questions, then please edit your post

Comment: I think the spirit of the "no shopping questions" rule is: "no questions where you ask us to pick out a part based on your specs". This is more a of a "how do I find X" question, which is allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are called thermopiles. This is what is used in IR temperature guns. They do not really have an upper limit on the range they can sense as far as I know. Well they do, but I don't think it's anywhere near 380C.

They come in metal TO-xx cans, not your TO-92 plastic package

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't heard of thermopiles until now. I am struggling to find any that operate in the range above 500°C though. Most I can find are limited to around 100°C

Comment: @Robert That is just what the output chart goes up to. Unless you mean you need it to operate in 500C, not measure 500C.

Comment: No, it would be operating in reasonable ambient temperatures (~25-40°C), but needs to measure something which is at 500. So even if the datasheet doesn't specify it, they will still be able to achieve this? Will calibration be needed to find its output at values that the charts don't show?

Comment: @robert Yes. It is a bit nonlinear. I don't know how high it goes but my understanding is IR guns don't use anything special.

Comment: For example, this one includes signal conditioning and is set to go up to 1000C and I don't think anything is special about the thermopile itself. https://www.melexis.com/en/product/MLX90616/Thermal-Infrared-Thermopile-Sensor-High-Temperature-Measurements